# How can I prove that $p → (q∨¬(p → q))$ is true?

Tags: logic

I know its true since Ive already filled out the truth table, but how can I prove it with out the truth table?

$$
p → (q∨¬(p → q))\\
¬p \lor (q∨¬(p → q))\\
¬p \lor (q∨¬(¬p → q))\\
¬p \lor (q∨¬(¬¬p → ¬ q))\\
¬p \lor (q∨¬(p \land ¬ q))
$$

Im stuck after this step.

Comment: I'd use a truth table.

Comment: Hint: write "P implies Q" a different way.

Comment: Telling us the context would be helpful.  Have DeMorgan's rules (laws, theorems) been introduced?  As others have indicated, truth tables are one valuable approach.  Another is to say out loud what the symbols mean.  The trickiest thing (for me) is what implication *if$\to$then* really means.  Write out that truth table, and go through it every way you can think of.

Comment: "Prove" using what??? It would be a slightly tricksy problem to set if you had to do it with the standard natural deduction rules ....!

Comment: Substitute for $a\to b$ the statement $\lnot b\lor a.$ Then your statement is equivalent to $$p\to \left(q\lor\lnot(\lnot p\lor q)\right)$$ and then again: $$\lnot p\lor \left(q\lor\lnot(\lnot p\lor q)\right)$$ Using $\lnot (a\lor b)=\lnot a\land \lnot b),$ and a few more equivalences,  show this is equivalent to: $$(\lnot p\lor q) \lor (p\land \lnot q)$$

Applying the distributive law, this is equivalent to:

$$(\lnot p\lor q\lor p)\land(\lnot p\lor q\lor\lnot q)\tag 1$$

But the left and right of (1) are true because $\lnot p\lor p$ and $q\lor\lnot q$ are true.

Comment: I know how I'd prove it, but the logical framework I'd use is not the one you might want to use.  For example if this is a textbook exercise, and your textbook lays out a set of rules for doing logical proofs, you need to follow those rules.  In that situation solution wouldn't help you, because I don't know what rules are given in your textbook and wouldn't be able to follow the right rules.  Can you say more about what kind of proof you are expected to produce?

Comment: Think Im only allowed to use: negation, absorption, De Morgan, distribution, Identity, idempotent, double negation law, commutative, associative, domination laws

Answer (score 2):

The easiest (depending on personal preferences, the way I outline below might be considered easier by some) way is to fill in this truth table:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
p & q & p\rightarrow q & q\lor \lnot(p\rightarrow q) & p \rightarrow (q\lor \lnot(p\rightarrow q))\\\hline
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$
(the third and fourth column are just to break down the expression where there is parentheses to make the problem easier, if you feel like it you can go directly for the fifth column, or add a new column between those two being the negation of the third, and if you can think of other ways to break the expression down, add those.)

Looking at it, it's probably possible by rewriting $p\rightarrow q$ to $\lnot p ? q$ (an operator replaced by a question mark to avoid giving everything away), and then using De Morgan's law and doing the first rewrite once more, you'll probably end up with a tautology.

Comment: Then shows us that, and tell why you don't think that solves the problem?

Comment: thanks for the answer forgot to say Ive already filled in the truth table. Trying to proof it now:                                                                                                                 p → (q∨¬(p → q))        ¬p V (q∨¬(p → q))        ¬p V (q∨¬(¬p → q))                       ¬p V (q∨¬(¬¬p → ¬ q))    ¬p V (q∨¬(p Ʌ ¬ q))

Comment: Stuck after this what would be the next steps?

Comment: If you have done more than the question shows, edit that into the question!

Comment: And learn a bit of LaTeX/MathJax so your writing isn't filled with v's and $\Lambda$'s.

Comment: edited my question